# Dapper.FastCrud InsertAsync doesn't update identity column

Tags: dapper, dapper-fastcrud

I am doing an InserAsync and the SQL query returns the generated Id but the entity has zero for its integer identity column.

Why is it not updating the identity column? It works when it's Insert but not when it's InsertAsync. Such is life...

Comment: Please also share a simplified source code that presents how you config your entity in FastCRUD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Insert without Async and returned `Task.FromResult(0);` from the method.

Boom, that will learn 'em.